# Why is LEFT JOIN deleting rows?

Tags: sql

I have been using sql for a long time,  but I am now working in Databricks and I am getting a very strange result. I have a table called block_durations with a set of ids (called block_ts), and I have another table called mergetable, which I want to left join to that table. Mergetable is indexed by acct_id and block_ts, so it has many different records for each block_ts. I want to keep the rows in block_durations that don't match, and if there are multiple matches in mergetable I want there to be multiple corresponding entries in the resulting join, as you would expect from a left join.

But this is not happening. In order to demonstrate this, I am showing the result of joining mergetable, after filtering for a single acct_id so that there is at most one match per block_ts.

```
select count(*) from mergetable where acct_id = '0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98'
```

> 16579

```
select count(*) from block_durations
```

> 82817

```
select count(*) from
(
      SELECT 
      mt.*,
      bd.block_duration
      FROM
      block_durations bd
      left outer JOIN mergetable mt
        ON mt.block_ts = bd.block_ts
      where acct_id='0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98'
) countTable
```

> 16579

As you can see, even though there are >80000 records in block_durations, most of them are getting lost in the left join. Why is this happening? I thought the whole point of a left join is that the non-matching rows of the left table are kept. This is exactly the behavior I would expect from an inner join -- and indeed when I switch to an inner join nothing changes.

Could someone please help me figure out what's going on?

-Paul

Comment: `WHERE` is still working. `NULL = '0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98'` => UNKNOWN and row is excluded from resultset

Comment: Not sure I see your point? I showed what happens after filtering for that acct_id -- we have 16000 rows. After than, it should be left joining to a table with 80000 rows, 16000 of which match. But the result should still be 80000 rows...

Comment: ahh... or maybe I do see your point. I need to add "OR acct_id is null"? or alternatively filter the mergetable in a subquery?

Comment: the result is 925000. still less than I would have thought -- there are around 80000 acct_id and 70000 block_ts. I would think this is going to give 70000 results for each acct id?

Answer (score 2):

All rows from left side of the join are preserved, but later on you run `WHERE ...` condition on that which removed rows not matching the condition.

Merge your `WHERE` condition into `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT 
mt.*,
bd.block_duration
FROM
block_durations bd
left outer JOIN mergetable mt
  ON mt.block_ts = bd.block_ts AND acct_id='0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98'
```

You can also filter `mergetable` before you run `JOIN` on the results:

```
SELECT 
mt.*,
bd.block_duration
FROM
block_durations bd
left outer JOIN (SELECT * FROM mergetable WHERE acct_id='0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98') mt
  ON mt.block_ts = bd.block_ts
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am a bit embarrassed to say that I didn't see this